# Does FIDE or USCF allow ICCF type numerical notation instead of the so called algebraic?

Tags: fide, notation

ICCF uses pure numerical notation counting each square by row and column  eg  11 to 88.  So Pd4 often written just d4 -  would be 2224 so there can never be any confusion should two pieces be able to move to the same square.

If One used that notation in an OTB tournament would FIDE accept it or would that be a problem?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that 1.d4 would correspond to 4244. Looks like you're thinking of the [Orangutan Opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokolsky_Opening), which would match your 2224. That's probably not great for championing this notation as causing less confusion than the algebraic one 

Comment: Also consider that people learn to "read" algebraic notation same as they learn to read a book. With practice, they can easily read algebraic notation in their head, without a board. That's not likely to translate to other notations, even if you can read them, it would be much slower... Think of reading a book in a language that uses a whole different alphabet.

Answer (score 5):

Neither appears to allow numerical notation.

[FIDE requires algebraic notation.](https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article)

> Article 8: The recording of the moves
>   8.1.1
>
> In the course of play each player is required to record his own moves
>   and those of his opponent in the correct manner, move after move, as
>   clearly and legibly as possible, in the algebraic notation (Appendix
>   C), on the ‘scoresheet’ prescribed for the competition.

[The USCF prefers algebraic, but also permits descriptive or "computer notation".](http://www.uschess.org/docs/gov/chessrules/US_Chess_Rule_Book-%20Online_Only_Edition_v7.1-1.2.11-7.19.19.pdf)

> 15. The Recording of Games15A. Manner of keeping score.In the course of play each player is required to record the game (both the player’s
>       and the opponent’s moves), move after move, as clearly and legibly as
>       possible, on the scoresheetprescribed for the competition. Algebraic
>       notationis standard, but descriptive or computer notation is
>       permitted.

I cannot find a definition for "computer notation" in their rules.

Comment: "Computer Notation" is where you record a move just by specifying the piece's original square and destination square - for example, instead of "1. e4" you might write "1. E2-E4".  Instead of "2. Nf3", you might write "2. G1-F3".  And so forth.

Comment: @patbarron Thanks, They did not officially define it. Even then, that is basically a long-form of algebraic, and thus, they still so not all the ICCF's notation.

Comment: FIDE allows the use of the native language abbrev for the piece being moved.   Why not say my language is the two digit home square?  Would FIDE really object to that??

Comment: I would think so. Go to the link I gave and look at the whole thing, including appendix C.

Comment: @edwinaoliver, that sounds a lot like "unsportsmanlike behaviour" (trying to take a piss at the referee, in this case)

Comment: OTOH, [that FIDE document linked](http://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article) seems to allow recording both the start and the ending squares of a move (C.8 Each move of a piece is indicated by the abbreviation of the name of the piece in question and the square of arrival. [...] A longer form containing the square of departure is acceptable. Examples: Bb2e5, Ng1f3, Ra1d1, e7e5, d2d4, a6a5.) That's not the same as numeric notation but should be equally unambiguous.

Comment: @ilkkachu The first part of the rule is very clear: Only algebraic. That you can use long form is just a footnote overall.

Comment: @PhishMaster, well, unless there's something there that's not obvious to someone not a priori familiar with the FIDE rules, 8.1.1 seems indeed to say algebraic notation is required. Then C.8 defines that the long form is an acceptable form of algebraic notation.